# MVC + POCO + Entity Framework, Passing Object between layers

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, poco

I am trying my hands on MVC 2, ADO.NET EF and POCO. I have generated my entity classes in a separate library using POCO generator.These POCO entities are used as ViewPages (Not sure if that's the right way to design or do I need separate ViewModels classes ?)

Now, if I take case of a simple scenario where I need to add an Employee object( which is related to a Department Master), what then should be the recommended way to transfer these objects between layers.

Layered structure of the application is somewhat like this :

[image]

I have thought of various alternatives:

I have a method in the Employee Controller which is named **AddEmployee()** which accepts the FormCollection as parameter. Within the form collection I get posted data such as Employee Name, Age , Salary etc and the ID of the Selected Department .

1.)  One way is that I can create another DTO say EmployeeDepartment DTO which will be used to map values from FormCollection as is. I can then break them at manager layer and use them to create entity objects i.e Employee Object and refer department by query similar to this:

```
e.Department =  Department.where(i => i.deptId == empDepDto.dept_id).first()
```

I am not a big fan of this and feel that every time there is a relation involved I have to add a DTO and then map it to my entity class.

2.) Second is probably the worst, i.e passing each object as parameter  and then couple them in manager layer.

3.) Use POCO as is, Create a Employee Object and Deparment Object at controller layer and pass the POCO object

```
public void AddEmployee(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    Department d = new Deparmtent; d.id = ""; //based on the dropdown value
    d.name="" //based on the dropdown selected text;

    Employee e = new Employee; e.Name. e. sal....

    e.Department = d;

    EmployeeManager.AddEmployee(e);
}
```

But at manager layer I think , I still need to recreate the reference to the Department using LINQ which again is repetitive and doesn't seems to be a clean solution.

Are there better ways of handling this ? Looking for recommendations and best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, is there any reason you're not using MVC version 3? There's no major breaking changes, so may as well upgrade?

Secondly is there a reason for using FormCollection rather than the strongly typed model-binding? Just change your views to use the strongly typed HTML helpers ( like `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property) %>`), or make sure the `name` attributes match the property names, and have your controller receive the type, and model binding will do the rest. There's plenty of tutorials showing this, and articles explaining it. Model binding will work with a name/value collection, like that posted as a form, or against JSON data, or you can find/write custom model binders that work against whatever wacky serialisation protocol you want.

One thing to watch though when passing the actual entity types that Entity Framework will store around, is that you have to be careful when updating existing objects, or with foreign key references to existing objects - all your objects must be attached to the right Entity Framework context. To achieve that you will often see the objects received by the controller having their properties copied to a freshly retrieved entity from a context, either manually or by an object mapper of some kind.

Comment: No specific reason for not choosing MVC 3. I hope question will still remain intact regardless of version.
I havent tried model binding but definitely can try using that and see how it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make a seperate project called "BusinessObjects" or "Model" which contains your POCOs.  Then use strongly typed model-binding for MVC and you'll be set.

The method signature will look something like this:

```
// In your Controller
public void AddEmployee(Employee newObject)
{
      YourDataContext dc = new YourDataContext();
      dc.Employees.Add(newObject);
      dc.SaveChanges();

}
```

Comment: :I don't think that's a clean solution. You controller should be completely persistent ignorant. You have used Entity context in the controller itself.

Comment: @Kunal, i think you've missed the point.  you're welcome to do the persistence in whatever layer you feel appropriate, but passing your poco's around is what you should be doing.  use strongly typed views and make use of the model binding for controller actions, and you'll be in better shape.

Comment: Ignore the persistance, you can move that out. The point to look at is the strongly typed input argument - which is model binding in action. However, there should be a return value though of type of ActionResult or one of its descendents. You'd normally specify post only via a HttpPost attribute, and return a redirect, which is the "post-redirect-get" pattern.

Comment: @Kunal It sounds like you control all the layers of your application. If that's the case, is there particular business reason you chose to write a multi-layered app? Cyan's answer is what I would recommend. Introducing layers will easily quadruple the amount of code you write and increase the likelihood of bugs. Choose the simplest architecture that meets your needs. You can always refactor it later.